# How to prevent JSESSIONID from being created if using DefaultCookieSerializer of spring 5.X with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-session

I am migrating to spring 5.X and configured `DefaultCookieSerializer` with cookieName "CUSTSESSION" for a domain called colombiaonline.com. This session is stored in redis using `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration`. 
`springSecurityFilterChain` is defined after `springSessionRepositoryFilter` in application context of spring.
Application is deployed on Tomcat 8. (`context.xml` `sessionCookieDomain` is set as "colombiaonline.com")

URL for application is dev.colombiaonline.com.

Now my issue is --
Two cookies are created

1. CUSTSESSION is created with domain colombiaonline.com as configured.
2. JSESSIONID is created for domain dev.colombiaonline.com which is not expected.

How to stop JSESSIONID from being created as it is causing problem?

Comment: You only partially did configuration. The `CookieSerializer` is a Spring Session class. Spring Security doesn't know anything about that, you will need to instruct Spring Security as well to use the `CUSTSESSION` as a session cookie, you didn't so it still expects/uses the default, which is `JSESSIONID`.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix the issue. It was only browser cache that was causing this issue. Configuration was correct and once I opened my site on incognito it worked for me.

However there is one more thing that we need to take care of is "sameSite" attribute. Default value for it is "Lax" which is different from "None". If you hop between sites and want session to be managed properly, configure sameSite properly as in my case earlier it was none but after migrating to 5.x it was set to "Lax" which was causing problem.
Refer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168365/is-setting-same-site-attribute-of-a-cookie-to-lax-the-same-as-not-setting-the-sa